# Glassfish Severe Warnings using Hibernate on MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, glassfish

I use Hibernate 3.6.10 as my ORM and MySQL as my database. I am having this wierd errors/warning when I run my web application. Can someone help me figure this out? Should I be worried about this errors/warnings?
I can still run the application, only these weird things keep showing up.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything weird in the screenshot above.  Am I missing something?  Do you mean the SEVERE label down the left-side of the log?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you posted the log in plaintext rather than as a screenshot. But from what I see, it seems to be self-explaining

- `hibernate.properties` is not found - that is ok, you can use `hibernate.cfg.xml`, they are equivalent
- you have an obsolete namespace in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, update it's header like in this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-xml-mapping/)
- `SessionFactory` is null but you will have to provide code if you need advice on that